# Parsing XML via xq (jq) with GNU Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, jq, gnu-parallel, xq

I have input xml file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2022-12-19T18:02:16+03:00">
 <shop>
  <offers>
   <offer id="177484701" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer1</url>
    ...
   </offer>
   <offer id="177485701" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer2</url>
    ...
   </offer>
   <offer id="177484401" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer3</url>
    ...
   </offer>
   ...
  </offers>
 </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

This file contain 2-8 million offers and after cleaning they take up 10 gigabytes.

I use the built-in functionality of xq without loops (processing time increases greatly with loops). Xq provided by python package yq and use jq.

```bash
cat file.xml | xq \
    --arg id "${id}" \
    --arg available "${available}" \
    --arg url "${url}" \
    -r '.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][] | "~~~\(.["@id"])~~~\(.["@available"])~~~\(.url)"' > /tmp/data.txt
```

But processing only uses 1 core. This file is updated periodically and needs to be processed as soon as possible. How can I parallel it via GNU parallel? It is possible with xq?

I tried different variants but they all give errors.

```bash
$ parallel -j8 --spreadstdin "xq --arg id '${id}' --arg available '${available}' --arg url '${url}' -r '.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][] | \"~~~\(.[\"@id\"])~~~\(.[\"@available\"])~~~\(.url)\"'" < file.xml > /tmp/data.txt

...
xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 4.
xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: no element found: line 11643, column 0.
...
```

```bash
$ cat file.xml | parallel --results output/{/} -q xq \
        --arg id "${id}" \
        --arg available "${available}" \
        --arg url "${url}" \
        -r '.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][] | "~~~\(.["@id"])~~~\(.["@available"])~~~\(.url)"' > /tmp/data.txt

...
usage: xq [-h] [--xml-output] [--xml-dtd] [--xml-root XML_ROOT]
          [--xml-force-list XML_FORCE_LIST] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files ...]
xq: error: argument files: can't open '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
...
```

```bash
$ parallel -j8 --pipepart --block 100M -a file.xml -k "xq --arg id '${id}' --arg available '${available}' --arg url '${url}' -r '.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][] | \"~~~\(.[\"@id\"])~~~\(.[\"@available\"])~~~\(.url)\"'" > /tmp/data.txt 

...
xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: no element found: line 801268, column 0.
xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 4.
xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 4.
...
```

Last variant seems illogical to me, because most likely the data breaks between cores. Rest of the proven variants are even more illogical.

Comment: Yes, it is, but you need to specify what you want to do. Firstly, on what level do you want to parallelize? Is it different input files? Is it different values provided as arguments to `--arg`? Is it the iteration in `.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][]`? Also, some actual input data would facilitate finding a solution that works for your use case. Lastly, what variants did you try? What errors did they give?

Comment: Post updated. I want parallel iterations in `.yml_catalog.shop.offers[][]` but it's part of the command xq.

Comment: If I had such large XML files to process that performance becomes relevant, 
I would compare the performance of [xq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support) 
and [yq --input-format xml](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/xml)

Comment: You cannot simply split the XML file into blocks of a fixed size because the resulting blocks are no longer valid XML files.
You get the error message `xq: Error running jq: ExpatError: ...` because you are feeding invalid XML into `xq`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to use `GNU parallel` for your task:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2022-12-19T18:02:16+03:00">
 <shop>
  <offers>
   <offer id="177484701" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer1</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177485702" available="false">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer2</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177484403" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer3</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177484404" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer4</url>
   </offer>
  </offers>
 </shop>
</yml_catalog>'

PARTITIONS=2   # number of partitions wanted

CODE_SPLIT_OFFERS='
  .yml_catalog.shop.offers.offer |
  _nwise((length - (length % $partitions)) / $partitions)
'

CODE_PROCESSING='.[] | "~~~\(.["@id"])~~~\(.["@available"])~~~\(.url)"'  # The code must be on one line in order to work with parallel

parallel --keep jq '-cr {1} <<< {2}' \
  ::: "$CODE_PROCESSING" \
  :::: <(xq -c --argjson partitions $PARTITIONS "$CODE_SPLIT_OFFERS" <<< "$INPUT")
```

**Output**

```
~~~177484701~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer1
~~~177485702~~~false~~~http:/site.com/offer2
~~~177484403~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer3
~~~177484404~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer4
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a solution with `GNU parallel` and this answer does not address that preference.
But maybe the following solution without `GNU parallel` will help you.

The idea is to divide the array `offers` into partitions of equal size (`PARTITIONS`) using the undocumented jq filter `_nwise` and then process each partition in a subshell in parallel.

I added a sample processing as placeholder for an arbitrary processing to the code below (filter available offers and extract the ID).
I also added code to merge the processing results at the end.

Note that this solution scrambles the offers. If this is undesired, you can sort the files by its sequential number before merging the results.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2022-12-19T18:02:16+03:00">
 <shop>
  <offers>
   <offer id="177484701" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer1</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177485702" available="false">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer2</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177484403" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer3</url>
   </offer>
   <offer id="177484404" available="true">
    <url>http:/site.com/offer4</url>
   </offer>
  </offers>
 </shop>
</yml_catalog>'

PARTITIONS=2   # number of partitions wanted
FILENAME_PARTITIONS="result_partition_"

CODE_SPLIT_OFFERS='
  .yml_catalog.shop.offers.offer |
  _nwise((length - (length % $partitions)) / $partitions)
'

CODE_PROCESSING='
  [.[] | select(."@available" == "true") |
  ."@id" |
  tonumber]
'

PARTITION=1
while read LINE
do
  echo "start processing partition $PARTITION"
  export FILENAME="${FILENAME_PARTITIONS}$PARTITION"
  jq -r -c "$CODE_PROCESSING" <<< "$LINE" > $FILENAME &
  ((PARTITION++))
done <<< $(xq -c --argjson partitions $PARTITIONS "$CODE_SPLIT_OFFERS" <<< "$INPUT")

echo -e "\nwait until all partitions are processed"
wait

echo -e "\nall partitions are processed. Processing results:"
find . -name "${FILENAME_PARTITIONS}*" -print -exec cat {} \;

echo -e "\nmerged results:"
jq -s -c 'flatten' <<< $(find . -name "${FILENAME_PARTITIONS}*" -exec cat {} \;)
```

**Output**

```
start processing partition 1
start processing partition 2

wait until all partitions are processed

all partitions are processed. Processing results:
./result_partition_2
[177484403,177484404]
./result_partition_1
[177484701]

merged results:
[177484403,177484404,177484701]
```

---

Exchange two pieces of the above code for an alternative processing:

```bash
CODE_PROCESSING='
  .[] | "~~~\(.["@id"])~~~\(.["@available"])~~~\(.url)"
'
```

```bash
echo -e "\nmerged results:"
find . -name "${FILENAME_PARTITIONS}*" -exec cat {} \;
```

**Output**

```
start processing partition 1
start processing partition 2

wait until all partitions are processed

all partitions are processed. Processing results:
./result_partition_2
~~~177484403~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer3
~~~177484404~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer4
./result_partition_1
~~~177484701~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer1
~~~177485702~~~false~~~http:/site.com/offer2

merged results:
~~~177484403~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer3
~~~177484404~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer4
~~~177484701~~~true~~~http:/site.com/offer1
~~~177485702~~~false~~~http:/site.com/offer2
```